# getindex for specific dims in Julia

Tags: julia

Suppose I want to write a dynamic function that gets an object subtype of `AbstractMatrix` and shuffles the values along a specified dimension. Surely there can be various approaches and ways to do this, but suppose the following way:

```
import Random.shuffle

function shuffle(data::AbstractMatrix; dims=1)
  n = size(data, dims)
  shuffled_idx = shuffle(1:n)
  data[shuffled_idx, :] #This line is wrong. It's not dynamic
```

A wrong way is to use several (actually indefinite) if-else statements like `if dims==1` do... `if dims==2` do. But it isn't the way to do these kinds of things. I could write `data::AbstractArray` then the input could have various dimensions. So this came to my mind that this can be possible if I can do something like `getindex(data, [idxs]; dims)`. But I checked for the `dims` keyword argument (or even positional one) in the dispatches of `getindex`, but there isn't such a definition. So how can I get values by specified indexes and along a `dim`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for `selectdim`:

```
help?> selectdim
search: selectdim

  selectdim(A, d::Integer, i)

  Return a view of all the data of A where the index for dimension d equals i.    
  Equivalent to view(A,:,:,...,i,:,:,...) where i is in position d.
```

Here's a code example:

```
function myshuffle(data::AbstractMatrix; dim=1)
    inds = shuffle(axes(data, dim))
    return selectdim(data, dim, inds)
end
```

Make sure not to use `1:n` as indices for `AbstractArray`s, as they may have non-standard indices. Use `axes` instead.

BTW, `selectdim` apparently returns a view, so you may or may not need to use `collect` on it.

Comment: Thanks! Precisely this is what I was looking for. And thanks for your advice. Indeed using `axes` is always better and safe in similar cases.

Comment: Maybe relevant: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/46215.